# How would i get yahoo keyword ranking for my website?

Tags: yahoo, seo

I am  working as search engine optimizer team lead in a company and facing problem in a project which name is http://www.Prooftech.com.sg...

Problem :-

The Website has 10 keywords for which my client wanted the top 10 Ranking in Yahoo Singapore search engine.

I have got top 10 ranking for the following 7 keywords Waterproofing, RC Roof ,Wall Leakages ,Ceiling Leakages , Water Leakages ,Roof Tile Coating ,Roof Tiles Repair in my 3 months work but still i am not getting the listing positions for Roof ,Concrete Repair ,Grouting ....

I have Done lot of Bookmarking ,Blog Commenting ,Blog Creations ,Press Release,Classified Ads to get these 3 keywords in listing but there is no changes in the results....

Can any help me out from this problem so i can get Good rankings for Roof ,Concrete Repair ,Grouting

Comment: This question would be better suited to [SE Webmasters] (http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

- More content in the lexical field of your keywords,
- Some dedicated landing page on your keyword,
- More diverse anchor for your out and inlink,
- More outlink from social network (viral operation, videos link...),
- More regular outlink (not just a blast one day...),
- Pay some influent blogger on your lexical field to write a really good article,
- Play with some Black/GreyHat linking tools like Xrumer/Zennoposter/Scrapebox/SenukeX
  ...

[image: SEO process]

Comment: Is anything more step by which i can do to get my particular keywords "Roof ,Concrete Repair ,Grouting" ranks soon?